# Kafka Consumer - Java (0.9 API)

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was looking at building a Kafka consumer using 0.9 API version. Please can you explain what is meant by consumer rebalance? What is the difference between consumer and co-ordinator referred to here? Also please can you explain consumer split brain problem?

> The following is a draft design that uses a high-available consumer
>   coordinator at the broker side to handle consumer rebalance. By
>   migrating the rebalance logic from the consumer to the coordinator we
>   can resolve the consumer split brain problem and help thinner the
>   consumer client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consumer rebalance means that the consumer groups is rebalancing the partitions between the consumers of that consumer groups, this happens when a new consumer enters or leaves the group.

Each consumer group has a co-ordinator that coordinates the group basically.

If you want to know more about the new consumer you can read [this](http://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0.9-consumer-client).

And split brain is a common issue with distribuited systems that happens when there is network partition and different parts of the system can not communicate between each other and don't realize about this. You can look it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_(computing))

Comment: Hi Nautilus , can consumer re balancing be done when using kafka api 0.8.2 version or is it available only in 0.9

Comment: Is the co-oridnator built into kafka and does it know the ips of all consuming applications?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not very familiar with the old consumer. You can ask here email:users@kafka.apache.org